# Click to continually remove specified number from margin

Tags: jquery, click, margin, increment

Really fundamental question here... I am using the below jQuery to shift some elements around the page.

```
$('.homeProducts .next').click(function() {
        $('.productContainer').css('margin-left',-284);
})
```

What I'd like to happen is every time the next element is clicked the container has it's margin reduced by 284. My code will work once, but that's it. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use relative values

> As of jQuery 1.6, .css() accepts relative values similar to
>   .animate(). Relative values are a string starting with += or -= to
>   increment or decrement the current value. For example, if an element's
>   padding-left was 10px, .css( "padding-left", "+=15" ) would result in
>   a total padding-left of 25px.

Try

```
$('.productContainer').css('margin-left','-=284');
```

Comment: Gah, I even tried that, just forgot the single quotes (admittedly I didn't think it would work but still...). Thanks for the help :)